# Origin of an old museum ticket

Tags: greek

Here is the ticket :

I have at home since several years a old ticket (originally, I thought it was a stamp) and I would like try to determine its value and where it was printed.
I think it is written in Greek but I don't understand the text because I don't speak a word of Greek. If you can help me, thanks =)

Here is the complete image with a new ticket. 
What is the abbreviation ΕΠ ? 
Thanks for this, I will already learn more about the Greek orator :)

[image: ticket]

[image]

Comment: This seems to be only a part of the image - there's some text cut of at the bottom. Would it be possible to post the complete image? I'm not sure if this is a stamp at all - εισιτήριο means ticket, not stamp; the abbreviation ΕΠ doesn't point to the greek postal service, the ΕΛΤΑ or ΕΤ ([Ελληνικά Ταχυδρομεία](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenic_Post)). The images shows the greek orator [Demosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosthenes) at the right and the [Pnyx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pnyx) on the Left.

Comment: i have edit the post ;)

Answer (score 13):

These are tickets to the archaeological sites of [Epidaurus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidaurus) (which includes the [still in use theatre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidaurus#Theatre)) and [Mycenae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycenae). In the Epidaurus ticket, the images are of the [Athenian Pnyx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pnyx) and the orator [Demosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosthenes). In the Mycenae ticket you can see the Lion Gate, as Pieter Geerkens [already mentioned](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/12174/1700).

The fine print on the left (the printing company's name) is written in [katharevousa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katharevousa). This and the price (70 drachmas) points to the tickets being issued sometime in the 70s or early 80s.

Answer (score 7):

The text above the first image is in both Greek alphabet and in English, the latter being:

> (He did did not seem to be resting, but his mind was in action and he seemed to be revolving some subtle plan ...)
>
> [Anthologia Palatina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatine_Anthology)

More on the background of the Palatine Anthology and it's significance is available [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=lNV6-HsUppsC&pg=RA2-PA365&lpg=RA2-PA365&dq=anthologia%20palatina%20translation&source=bl&ots=QnJMoX9AyI&sig=8TlKvDV-pwgjiS_Kl-Oz18acoUg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m-UuU-rZB6LcyQGdy4DIDw&ved=0CGMQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=anthologia%20palatina%20translation&f=false) (pp 362)

[image]

The Palatine Anthology was *discovered* in Heidelberg in 1606, and is a collection of approximately 3700 epigrams, or poems, derived from the collection compiled by the Byzantine *protopapas* (archpriest) Constantine Cephelas around 900 AD.

The second image is of the [Lion Gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_Gate) in [Mycenae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycenae):
[image]

and is accompanied by a poem fragment that is attributed to the [*Greek Anthology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Anthology), which  is the collective title for the [*Palatine Anthology*](http://books.google.ca/books?id=LbqF8z2bq3sC&pg=PA411&lpg=PA411&dq=planudea%20anthology&source=bl&ots=laDtmpzueX&sig=2hyR_9Y4cCmYMVAbZWfxeEFWYeM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mOouU7qTJMbuyAGr14HoDw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=planudea%20anthology&f=false) and the smaller [*Planudea Anthology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_of_Planudes).

The text underneath the first image translates into English as [*Archaia Epidavros*](http://www.epidavros.eu/ancient-epidavros/), the current name for a small fishing village at the east coast of the Peloponnese.

The text above the price on both stamps translates into Latin lettering as *Eisithirion*, the Greek word for *ticket*. (Observe also the perforations along the left edge of both images.)

**Update**:
OP's guess that they are museum tickets might explain the dual Greek/English wording.

Comment: Hmm - if it's ticket dating from 2006, i think it wouldn't use drachma as currency. Besides, initially, the euro/drachma equivalent was 1:340, so 70 drachma would be about 20 eurocent today (on that base, i assume the tickets are quite old). Regarding Demosthenes: there's a caption beneath the portrait, denoting demosthenes (as well as below the pnyx).

Comment: In fact, I have this ticket for years (since about 1980), an old man give me these tickets before dying. 
So it can not be 2006 :)
I guess also that is museum ticket because this man travelled in lot of country. 
But the mystery remains on the date? and therefore this ticket has no value? Damage: D

Comment: @newuser: You would have to talk to a collector before assuming that they have no value. They are in good condition, and care was taken in the producing the image quality, so they may be collector's items. Making that judgement is not part of the expertise of this site.

Comment: ok you think it could date from when?

Comment: Eisithirion is indeed the Greek word for ticket.

Comment: Thanks you very much everyone =) I look at the different answers I thought I think you have answered all my questions :)

Answer (score 3):

I **guess** those are greek tickets ([εισιτηριον](http://translate.google.com/#el/en/%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD)) for excavation sites or museums. The EP and MYK correspond to the location, ancient [epidaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidaurus) (Palaia epidauros, ancient epidauros) and mykene.

The vertical writing on the left points to the printing company, [Aspioti-ELKA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspioti-ELKA) that was declared bancrupt in 1997.

Answer (score 0):

I found a twin for both tickets pasted into my mother’s diary for July 1982, when she and my father did a tour of Greece. These were her proof of payment for visiting these two historic sites (July 18 and 21). She said the guides were exceptionally entertaining and informative. Bought a book about Mycenae in a gift shop at the “archaic temple”.